# Why does my Monero wallet refresh so slowly?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-cli, mymonero, privatekey

Refreshing a wallet generated from **MyMonero** private keys, it is refreshing at a rate that will take hours to complete. I use `CTRL-c` to stop the refresh and it helps by then moving to a higher block height, but this doesn't change the slow refresh rate.

**Monerod** (on Win10 laptop with 4 GB and SSD drive) is up and synced.

I find this curious. Wallets created at the same time are refreshing as per my normal experiences, a few minutes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details like: operating system, 64 or 32 bit, whether home computer or VPS, general processing power, and any other information that leads you to believe the sync speeds would likely be the same.  Those details may not matter, but they may.

Comment: Did you enter a restore height when you created your wallet in monero-wallet-cli? If you didn't, every block since height 0 will be scanned, which will take many hours.

Comment: @Jaquee "many hours" is almost certainly incorrect, though it will certainly vary depending on hardware. I just did a test restore from height 0 on my (admittedly pretty speedy) machine: 16 minutes.

Comment: With Monerujo Android it doesn't happen and with Linux Ubuntu 18.04 64bit it does with GUI or without GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Monero software has improved a lot the speed of refresh, be sure to have the right version from [GetMonero.Org](https://ww.getmonero.org/downloads/) installed.

Also, if you're using a remote node, try to check if another node is faster.